# Can I repeat a macro with the "dot operator"?

Tags: macro, count

Can I repeat a macro with the `.` command? For example, I'd like to be able to type:

```
@q...
```

and have it effectively call `@q` 4 times. With the default behavior, this works only if 'q' holds a single command, for example `dw`, `x`, or `iHello<esc>`. (This makes sense though, since '.' repeats the last *change*, not the last keystrokes/command)

I'd also love to have this work with counts. For example, typing:

```
3@q.
```

would be effectively the same as running `@q` 6 times. How can I configure this behavior?

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking for, but maybe it will be helpful https://github.com/wincent/replay . This records lastly recorded macro and replays it on pressing `Enter`

Comment: FYI, `@@` repeats the last macro, so if you are asking this for the sake of mappings and such, it should work for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Give this a try. It remaps `@` so that `g@` (plus a dummy motion `l`) is used afterwards, thus becoming the last operator and subject to repeating with `.`.

```
" When . repeats g@, repeat the last macro.
fun! AtRepeat(_)
    " If no count is supplied use the one saved in s:atcount.
    " Otherwise save the new count in s:atcount, so it will be
    " applied to repeats.
    let s:atcount = v:count ? v:count : s:atcount
    " feedkeys() rather than :normal allows finishing in Insert
    " mode, should the macro do that. @@ is remapped, so 'opfunc'
    " will be correct, even if the macro changes it.
    call feedkeys(s:atcount.'@@')
endfun

fun! AtSetRepeat(_)
    set opfunc=AtRepeat
endfun

" Called by g@ being invoked directly for the first time. Sets
" 'opfunc' ready for repeats with . by calling AtSetRepeat().
fun! AtInit()
    " Make sure setting 'opfunc' happens here, after initial playback
    " of the macro recording, in case 'opfunc' is set there.
    set opfunc=AtSetRepeat
    return 'g@l'
endfun

" Enable calling a function within the mapping for @
nno <expr> <plug>@init AtInit()
" A macro could, albeit unusually, end in Insert mode.
ino <expr> <plug>@init "\<c-o>".AtInit()

fun! AtReg()
    let s:atcount = v:count1
    let c = nr2char(getchar())
    return '@'.c."\<plug>@init"
endfun

nmap <expr> @ AtReg()
```

I've tried to handle as many corner cases as I can think of. You can
repeat `@:` with `.`. Counts to `@` or `.` are retained for subsequent
presses of `.`.

This is tricky, and I'm not convinced that something won't break
somewhere along the way. So no guarantees, warranties, or promises with
this one.

Personally, I'm okay having a difference between the fine-grained
repeats of `.` for the last change, and the macro repeats of `@@`.

**EDIT**

I figured, having gone this far, that I may as well add some additional code that will allow pressing `.` immediately
after recording a macro to play it back.

```
fun! QRepeat(_)
    call feedkeys('@'.s:qreg)
endfun

fun! QSetRepeat(_)
    set opfunc=QRepeat
endfun

fun! QStop()
    set opfunc=QSetRepeat
    return 'g@l'
endfun

nno <expr> <plug>qstop QStop()
ino <expr> <plug>qstop "\<c-o>".QStop()

let s:qrec = 0
fun! QStart()
    if s:qrec == 1
        let s:qrec = 0
        return "q\<plug>qstop"
    endif
    let s:qreg = nr2char(getchar())
    if s:qreg =~# '[0-9a-zA-Z"]'
        let s:qrec = 1
    endif
    return 'q'.s:qreg
endfun

nmap <expr> q QStart()
```

Comment: This works fantastic! Since posting this question, my workflow has changed, so I don't really want to be able to repeat macros with dot anymore. However, this works really well, so I'll accept it anyway (though I probably won't add it to my `.vimrc`)

Comment: No worries, interesting problem regardless!

Comment: Edit: allow playing back a macro with `.` immediately after recording.

Comment: I think `\<plug>qstop` should be before `q` in the QStart function

Comment: @Antony The second snippet of code doesn't work anymore (the original code still does).  Any chance you know what the fix is?

Answer (score 10):

To repeat your last macro you can use `@@` so `3@@` would essentially run @q 3 times. However the @ keystrokes can be unwieldy, so in my .vimrc I have the lines:

```
  "- Lazy macro repeat
  nmap <leader>m @@
```

This allows me to use my leader key (,) plus m to run the last macro. Then you can precede this with a number to repeat the macro.

Now `3,m` is equivalent of `3@@`. Same total keys and no need to hold shift.

**EDIT**:  Upon rethinking this I came up with a new macro.
  `nmap <leader>. @@`
This also works when preceded by a number so `3,.` is now `3@@` Would love to see this work so that I could pass in a macro letter and have that macro repeat instead of the last macro.

Comment: The OP wants `3@q.` to run `@q` 6 times. This doesn't do that.

Comment: Rereading your question I'm not sure this answers it.  Can you give an example of when you would use `3@q.`? It would seem you might as well just prepend it with a count.   I tend to set a search before beginning a macro then use `n` in the macro to jump to the start of where it can be replayed.

Answer (score 6):

You can record the use of a macro in another macro, and repeat that.

```
qqdwq
qr2@qq
```

Now `3@r` is like running `@q` six times.

Answer (score 2):

By default `space` in vim is "move right 1 character" which is already covered by `l`, so I've remapped space to re-run a macro from the q buffer:

```
noremap <Space> @q
```

To use, just record a macro with `qq` first, stop recording with `q` and then hit `space` to replay.

Comment: FYI, for the reason you state (it's not a required key) a lot of people use space as their leader key so there might not be as many people with it free as you think. :)

Comment: If you have dvorak remapped then it is noremap <Space> @'

Answer (score 1):

As I don't use `,` and like a simple easy to type solution, this works for me:

```
:map , @@
```

Comment: You Sir like to live dangerously.